# Get min max of sliderInput in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `sliderInput` element in my `ui.R` for which I determine the `min` and the `max` value dynamically (actually I use a module, where the values are determined from a data set).

What I would like to do now is to read the `min/max` values in my `server.R`. Of course I could use the same code and determine `min/max` again, but I was wondering whether it is not possible to get the `min/max` values from the element directly?

Comment: When you calculate your `min/max`, they should be already available?! Simply store them in `reactives()` or in `reactiveValues()` and reuse them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the two answers, I feel that the solution would be to pass an extra argument to my module containing the `min/max` values. Overall, the `ui.R` renders finally to `html` and I am not sure whether conceptually you should even try to access the `html` from the `server.R`

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you could set up reactives to calculate `min` and `max`, and then use a `renderUI` function to make the sliderInput.

I think you should already be using `renderUI` within your module, so this isn't a big workaround.

Answer (score 2):

How can you determine dynamic/reactive `min` and `max` values in UI?

The most reasonable solution is to move slider to server.R

UI.R

```
uiOutput("slider")
```

Server.R

```
output$slider <- renderUI({
     maxkaw <- max(...)
     minkaw <- min(...)

     sliderInput("slider","", min   = minkaw, 
                 max   = maxkaw,
                 value = c(minkaw,maxkaw))
   })
```

Comment: Well, I use a module, where the `data.frame` is an argument and with that I can determine `min/max` dynamically.