# Shiny R "ERROR: non-numeric argument to binary operator" while trying to pass a variable from server to ui

Tags: r, shiny, slider

Obviously am doing something wrong here or not doing enough. I need to set the `min`, `max` and `value` of a `sliderInput` using one column from the .xlsx data that am uploading.

**UI**

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    sliderInput(
      "man",
      "Time Interval",
      min = min("time"),
      max = max("time"),
      value = c(min("time"), max("time"))
    )

  )),
  dashboardBody(
    wellPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Choose XLSX File"),
      downloadButton("downloadReport", "Generate Report")
    ),
    textOutput("time"),
    box(
      title = "Position",
      width = "100%",
      plotOutput("plot1", height = 450)
    )
  )

)
```

**SERVER**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  my_data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    dataRaw <- read.xlsx(inFile$datapath)

  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(my_data()))
      return(NULL)
    str(my_data())
    plot(my_data()$Position.X,
         my_data()$Position.Y,
         xlab = "Distance (X)",
         ylab = "Distance (Y)")

  })

  output$time <- reactive({
    if (is.null(my_data()))
      return(0)
    my_data()$Time

  })

}
```

**FILES**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wObfHrFz2hMg3M5xfANzCuHwvpc6wKbi?usp=sharing

**ERROR**

ERROR: non-numeric argument to binary operator

The error happens at the lines

```
min = min("time"),
max = max("time"),
value = c(min("time"), max("time"))
```

but the line

```
textOutput("time"),
```

does get the variable `time`.

I have shared the files and input data. Thank you!

Comment: `"time"` is a character, and `min` and `max` only accept numeric arguments. If you have a column "Time" in your dataset, you should put `min(my_dataset$time)` instead (and same thing for `max`). `textOutput` accepts `"time"` because the inputId needs to be a character argument

Comment: @bretauv i cant access my_data from UI. But thank you. I manged to get it done by using renderUI as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846677/get-min-max-of-sliderinput-in-shiny

Comment: then you should use `uiOutput` instead of the slider and use `renderUI` to create the slider only when the data imported is not NULL

Comment: @bretauv just did that! :)

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: @bretauv yes it did. thank you!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to post a clean solution as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using `renderUI` as in [Get min max of sliderInput in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846677/get-min-max-of-sliderinput-in-shiny)

In my ui.R code I replaced the `sliderInput(...)` part with `uiOutput("slider")` and in server.R replaced the `output$time <- reactive({...})` part with:

```
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(my_data()))
      sliderInput("slider",
                  "",
                  min   = 0,
                  max   = 0,
                  value = c(0, 0))
    maxkaw <- max(my_data()$Time)
    minkaw <-  min(my_data()$Time)

    sliderInput(
      "slider",
      "Min-Max",
      min   = minkaw,
      max   = maxkaw,
      value = c(minkaw, maxkaw)
    )
  })
```